# Cant config BroadCast Receiver for images or pictures , manifest file

Tags: android, android-widget

Im trying to create a BroadCast receiver to be reference to pictures in device (like PicSay and others apps) and I cant figure out why it's not working.

the code in Receiver is just a Log tag.

maybe is something in manifest:

```
        <receiver android:name=".PicReceiver" 
        android:label="pics" 
        android:description="@string/app_name" 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

The curret code not need to use BroadCastReceiver (until here...) (for show the icon to reference to images as example)

Here is the code :

```
 <activity android:name=".PicReceiver" 
    android:label="pics" 
    android:description="@string/app_name" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: `<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />` was the solution